# Full Tax Summary Display 2 tax but one result

Tags: magento2, tax

When I display the full tax summary in my cart (and in checkout) I get the tax amount but for only the first tax have a value (the total of all tax)

The total cart amount is :34.98
The total of tax is 5.24

So the first tax (TPS 5%) should be 34.98$ * 0,05 = 1.75$
And the second tax (TVQ 9.975%) should be equal: 34.98 * 0,09975 = 3.49$

So the total is correct, but why I don't have the amount for each tax  ?

See image below:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I'm searching for solution for this one too... if you found an answer, can you please share it, thank you.